# Unable to access Wallet in Multibit HD - currupt password

Tags: wallet, multibit, backup

After my computer died and was rebuilt I'm trying to restore access to my bitcoin wallet.

I have my wallet words with I've confirmed are correct as I've used them in the past.

I try to restore my wallet by entering my wallet words, which are accepted, then select my backup which is located correctly.
Then I get the restore report saying
 Backup location created
 Wallet Created
 security certificates
 wallet is synchronising. please wait until complete.

but as the wallet fails to create I don't think it can synchronise. the screen stays like this until I cancel.